# How to Inspect fetch call and Return same Call

Tags: javascript, promise, greasemonkey, fetch-api

I need a way of taking a promise, calling .then on it to inspect the returned value, and then to return this promise exactly as it was to other parts of the system. The context is I'm trying to modify the fetch API from a GraseMonkey script so that I can modify the data returned. I inspect this by calling .json() on the response. However if I don't modify the data, I need to return an object exactly representing the original call to the fetch API so that the page's code sees no difference. But when I have tried returning the object, I get an error that the response has already been consumed and now I'm lost in a stack of Promises that I can't seem to get to work out (I'm not a JS native)

The code  below is what I have already and it works, but it's not really acceptable as it duplicates every other request that's not being mangled.

```
function newFetch(){
    if (needsToBeModified(arguments[0])) {

        response = null;
        return oldFetch.apply(this, arguments)
            .then(r => {
                response = r;
                return r.json();
            })
            .then(
                j => {
                    j = processJSON(j);
                    return new Promise((resolve, rej) => {
                        response.json = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(j));
                        resolve(response);
                    });
                },
                (fail) => {
                    return oldFetch.apply(this, arguments)
                    //How can I avoid making this call here again?
                }
            );
    } else {
        return oldFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    }      
}
```

Please could someone tell me a way of peeking at the json, and if this throws an error, returning the original promise from fetch without needing to make the call again?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem that you have to call `.json()` on the `fetch()` result to get the value so that means that you can no longer return the original value (because the stream has already been read).  It that what you're trying to ask?  Very confusing question.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the question, to determine whether the result is json, or to get it as plain text, I have to consume it and fulfil the promise. The second part is that what I need to return must look exactly like the result from the original fetch call.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please indicate that to the community and "accept" the best answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of that answer.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` returns a promise that resolves to a [response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).  One of the methods on that response object is [`.clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) which sounds like it does just what you want.  From the doc for `.clone()`:

> The clone() method of the Response interface creates a clone of a response object, identical in every way, but stored in a different variable.
>
> clone() throws a TypeError if the response Body has already been used. In fact, the main reason clone() exists is to allow multiple uses of Body objects (when they are one-use only.)

I think you can use that like this:

```
function newFetch(){
    let p = oldFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    if (needsToBeModified(arguments[0])) {
        let origResponse, cloneResponse;
        return p.then(r => {
            origResponse = r;
            cloneResponse = r.clone();
            return r.json();
        }).then(j => {
            j = processJSON(j);
            // monkey patch .json() so it is a function that resolves to our modified JSON
            origResponse.json = () => Promise.resolve(j);
            return origResponse;
        }, fail => {
            // return clone of original response
            if (cloneResponse) {
                return cloneResponse;
            } else {
                // promise was rejected earlier, don't have a clone
                // need to just propagate that rejection
                throw fail;
            }
        });
    } else {
        return p;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @jfriend suggested, you will need to [`clone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) the response so that your caller can consume it again after you inspected the JSON:

```
function newFetch(urlOrRequest) {
    var promise = oldFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    if (needsToBeModified(urlOrRequest)) {
        return promise.then(response =>
            response.clone().json().then(obj => {
                const result = Promise.resolve(processJSON(obj));
                response.json = () => result;
                return response;
            }, jsonErr => {
                return response;
            })
        );
    } else {
        return promise;
    }      
}
```

Or better yet, instead of returning the old, unaltered response with a patched `json` method, just [create a new one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response):

```
function newFetch(urlOrRequest) {
    var promise = oldFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    if (needsToBeModified(urlOrRequest)) {
        return promise.then(response =>
            response.clone().json().then(obj => {
                const result = JSON.stringify(processJSON(obj));
                return new Response(result, response);
            }, jsonErr => response)
        );
    } else {
        return promise;
    }      
}
```

Alternatively, the easiest way to go would be to defer your `processJSON` call into the overwritten `json` method:

```
…
if (needsToBeModified(urlOrRequest)) {
    return promise.then(response =>
        response.json = function() {
            return Response.prototype.json.call(this).then(processJSON);
        };
        return response;
    });
}
…
```

Comment: Is the last version not missing the `jsonErr => response` catch?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 No. The client calling our `.json()` should receive the same error as if he called the real `.json()` method.

Comment: that last one is genius

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand that question to say that sometimes you need to alter the result of an async operation depending it's arguments

There's no need to perform the operation twice, and I think the OP code can be dramatically simplified as follows:

```
function newFetch() {
    return oldFetch.apply(this, arguments).then(r => {
        return (needsToBeModified(arguments[0]))? processJSON(r.json()) : r;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, as we don't know that the returned value will be json. And secondly, if it is, the modifued value gas to be wrapped into a promise (for the json function), which is wrapped into another promise (for the fetch funxtion)